# Stolen Macbook Pro, want to gain remote access

Tags: macbook, dropbox, remote-access

Hey guys I had a Macbook pro stolen. When I talked to the police they essentially told me there was nothing to do.  Since then, I have read more about tracking down stolen macs and just last night read about using Dropbox to get a "last use" IP address.

1. I got the IP address and did some geolocating but only to the point that I know the town it is in.  I gave the police this information and they said they would contact the ISP to try and get the street address.
2. The Macbook was stolen about a week ago so I am trying to gather as much info as possible before its really too late and therefore I'm doing some detective work on the side.

Here is the details of my Mac:

1. It runs the most recent OS
2. There was a single user that was password protected with administrative access
3. I did not have terminal running, or any theft security besides my password
4. I do not use iCloud
5. The Dropbox hasn't been used in a few days (worries me it is wiped or turned off)

I read a post about remotely being able to access the computer. 
My questions:

1. Can I get Dropbox to run again or use Dropbox in a way that re-activates it on the stolen lap top?
2. How difficult would it be to AppleScript a command that started remote access?

The article I read was going to attempt to send a script through Dropbox and hope it would open.

Essentially I am looking for any non "wait on the police" help I can get. I have the IP address, now I want a bit more.

Comment: The fact that you have the IP address is a blessing.  The police can get the customer data from the ISP associated with the IP address.  Thats far better than my friend who had his iPad stolen.  Using the find my iPad feature, he located the iPad to an apartment building, but the police told him that unless he could pinpoint the apartment, there was nothing they could do.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! not used to the superuser format

Comment: Man, I am really sorry to hear that.  Though as @Keltari said, that is very fortunate to have the IP (great way to find it, by the way).  I don't mean to discourage you, but I highly doubt you'll be able to remote access since that requires either a) A service running (teamviewer, hamachi, etc) or b) Router port forwarding (and generally a service like SSH, etc) - so sometimes it requires both.  You could do some port scanning on the presumed theif's IP to see if there is a possible vulnerability in.  But that then puts you in some grey areas (and some definite black ones).

Comment: This is exactly why any mobile device that is not chained to my desk is dual layer encrypted with a strong key phrase. I don't care about someone stealing my computer. I worry about them stealing the data on my computer. Stealing my computer makes me angry. Stealing my data makes me feel violated.

Answer (score 0):

If they have access to your gmail account, you might get the IP from gmail. As well, you could email yourself an enticing applescript that opens up some access to your machine. Check the legality though as you might be liable get into trouble if you invade the privacy of some poor sap who bought the machine from the thief.